# ¿Hay ejemplos de como usar "Confirm" de Acr.UserDialogs en Xamarin.forms?

Tags: android, c#, xamarin.forms

Recientemente hice una app de Xamarin.forms en la que deshabilité el BackButton del hardware.

Esto lo hice para que la App no quede en segundo plano cuando el usuario quiera salir y use solo los botones de la App.

A raíz de esto, hice un botón para que pueda salir en el cual utilicé 
[Acr.UserDialogs](https://github.com/aritchie/userdialogs) (lo cual me resultó muy útil y practico para muchas cosas) para mostrar una ventana en la que pueda confirmar que quiere salir.

Dentro del Clicked del boton está lo siguiente:

```
private void btnCerrar_Clicked(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
{
    msj.CerrarAppAsync();
}
```

Como pueden ver, el botón llama al método `CerrarAppAsync()` que se encuentra dentro de otra clase.

En ese método está el siguiente código:

```
public async void CerrarAppAsync()
{
    var confirmaSalir = new ConfirmConfig();
    confirmaSalir.Title = "Saliendo de la App";
    confirmaSalir.Message = "Está seguro que desea salir?";
    confirmaSalir.OkText = "Si";
    confirmaSalir.CancelText = "No";

    bool result = await UserDialogs.Instance.ConfirmAsync(confirmaSalir);

    if (result == true){
        if (Device.OS == TargetPlatform.Android){
            DependencyService.Get<IAndroidMethods>().CloseApp();
        }
    }else{
        return;
    }
}
```

Esto funciona bien y cierra la App sin problemas, pero realmente lo que me gustaría es que el método me retorne un valor booleano en lugar de cerrar la App ya que luego podría utilizar ese método para mas cosas. Pero el problema que tengo es que el dispositivo no muestra el Dialog hasta que se ejecuta todo el código del botón.

Entonces si yo dejo el código del botón así:

```
private void btnCerrar_Clicked(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
{
    bool sale = msj.CerrarAppAsync();
    if (sale == true){
        //Aquí va el código para cerrar.
    }
}
```

El Dialog no se va a mostrar hasta después de haber pasado por el if.

Hay algo que esté haciendo mal o simplemente no se puede hacer lo que quiero?

Gracias a todos de antemano!

Comment: no se xamarin.. pero es un await task.. por lo tanto no falta un await en la llamada msj.CerrarAppAsync()?

Comment: Era tan simple como eso... yo había intentado hacerlo con un Task.Run( () => { msj.CerrarAppAsync(); }); y no me habia funcionado... Ponelo como respuesta así lo marco!! muchas gracias

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Las llamadas a metodos asincronicos para los cuales se deba esperar una respuesta se hacen usando la instruccion Await.

De no ser asi, las llamadas se hacen async pero el codigo se ejecuta linealmente, con lo cual las instrucciones siguientes siguen su curso normal.

Para arreglar el problema que estas teniendo, debes hacer:

```
private async void btnCerrar_Clicked(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
{
    bool sale = await msj.CerrarAppAsync();
    if (sale == true){
        //Aquí va el código para cerrar.
    }
}
```

La funcion debe estar decorada con async, y la llamada a la funcion asincronica debe ser utilizando la instruccion await